# OAuth2 Token expiration time in c#

Tags: c#, uwp

i am writeing app on uwp. I must get token from login.live.com, but i don't know how to get expiration time of this token. I have that code:

```
        var tokenProvider = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync(_webProviderId);
        var tokenRequest = new WebTokenRequest(tokenProvider, Scopes.ToString());
        var tokenRequestResult = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(tokenRequest);
        if (tokenRequestResult.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
        {
            var tokenResponse = tokenRequestResult.ResponseData.First();
            Token.SetToken(tokenResponse.Token, 3600); // add server expiration time
            Scopes.Updated = true;
        }
        else { throw new Exception("Token provider error"); }
```

Comment: Do you need the expiration time for any purpose other than Authenticating with WebAuthenticationCoreManager? It should handle refreshing the token automatically.

Comment: @nimatra it's mean that token in string don't have "expiration time"?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it does but WebAuthenticationCoreManager is taking care of refreshing it.

Answer (score 0):

The http response received for token request will have a parameter called "expires_in". From this value, you should be able to derive the duration by which the token will expire. Check the [OAuth2.0 Live Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx) documentation.